# How to make SQL Server 2008 R2 trace work like it did in previous versions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I just upgraded from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2008 R2.  I went to create a trace, but now it's asking me to pick which options to show in the trace and it doesn't select any of them by default.  I'm trying to get a trace that works like it did in previous versions of SQL Server, but I can't figure out which options to check in the Trace Properties dialog.  I mainly just want to see anytime someone makes any kind of query to the database (the way it worked in previous versions of SQL Server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the default template must have changed to blank in R2.

You can set the default to one of your choosing by going into File -> Templates -> Edit Template

In SQL2008 RTM the default template is called "Standard"